# Signature image and date on same line hfill not working and wrapping into new line

Tags: pdftex, texlive, knitr

I am trying to prefill the signature and date on a document as follows. Everything looks right, except the date wraps into new line instead of sitting on the same line as the signature image.

What am I doing wrong?

```
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{46.5em}
\vspace*{0.2cm}\noindent\includegraphics[width=6cm, height=2cm, keepaspectratio = true, left]{dan-signature.png} \hfill \textbf{\today}
\vspace*{0.2cm}\textbf{LABORATORY DIRECTOR SIGNATURE\hfill DATE{\textcolor{Fuchsia}{\large\\Latex User GT, B.S U}}
}\end{minipage}}
```

When I remove the `\hfill \today` the page looks the way I want, except I want the current date right above the text DATE in the next line. Additionally, I want the name of the person in the following line, as it also correctly appears without that `\hfill \today` portion of the code.

[image]

Comment: I'm doing this from memory; I hope I don't mess up.  No minipage needed if the textwidth is what you want; this works to make the last line of a paragraph flush right:  `{\unskip\parfillskip=0pt\par}` goes right after the last text in the paragraph.  Use `\hfil` instead of `\hfill`, since your paragraph is only one line long.  The braces ensure that the zero `\parfillskip` doesn't persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{46.5em}
\vspace*{0.2cm}
\includegraphics[width=6cm, height=2cm, keepaspectratio=true]{example-image-a} \hfill \textbf{\today} \par
\vspace*{0.2cm}
\textbf{LABORATORY DIRECTOR SIGNATURE} \hfill \textbf{DATE} \par
\textcolor{Fuchsia}{\large\textbf{Latex User GT, B.S U}}
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!